# AMPscript Lookuprows difficulties

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup

I have some difficulties on my ampscript code.

Context of the situation : I have this data extension
[image]

`Product_Id` is the primary key of this data extension.

I am coding by using ampscript so as to display in an email all the products and the KPI associated and this for a client (here a client is a subscriberkey).

Example :

If I schedule a sending on this data extension, I want for example the client 123ABC to receive an email with this content :

```
    Product_Type = BC
    Product_Id : A1 ; KPI_BC = 12
    Product_Id : A2 ; KPI_BC = 23
    
    Product_Type = RP
    Product_Id : A3 ; KPI_RP = 2
    
    Product_Type = SI
    Product_Id : A4 ; KPI_SI = 5
    
    Product_Type = Co
    Product_Id : A5 ; KPI_Co = 11
```

And the client 003DEFG to receive

```
Product_Type = BC
Product_Id : B1 ; KPI_BC = 34
Product_Id : B2 ; KPI_BC = 21

Product_Type = RP
Product_Id : B3 ; KPI_RP = 4
```

By using this exemple here : https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/
I managed to display the product and the KPI associated but I didn't manage to make the link between the client and the products that he purchased.

If I take again the example of the client 123ABC, my code will send him this :

```
Product_Type = BC
Product_Id : A1 ; KPI_BC = 12
Product_Id : A2 ; KPI_BC = 23
**Product_Id : B1 ; KPI_BC = 34
Product_Id : B2 ; KPI_BC = 21**

Product_Type = RP
Product_Id : A3 ; KPI_RP = 2
Product_Id : B3 ; KPI_RP = 4

Product_Type = SI
Product_Id : A4 ; KPI_SI = 5

Product_Type = Co
Product_Id : A5 ; KPI_Co = 11
```

In my idea, I created 4 differents lookuprows (so 4times the code here https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/). Each one display the products and the KPI associated. However, in all my 4 lookuprows I want to display only the products of the clients and not all the products.

For the moment, this is my ampscript code :

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @Product_Type, @i
set @Product_Type= "BC" 
set @rows = LookupRows("My_Data_Extension","Product_Type", @Product_Type)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @KPI_BC, @Product_Id
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
    set @Product_Id = field(@row,"Product_Id")
    set @KPI_BC = field(@row,"KPI_BC")
    ]%%
Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Product_Id: %%=v(@Product_Id)=%%, KPI_BC: %%=v(@KPI_BC)=%%

%%[next @i ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @Product_Type, @i
set @Product_Type= "RP" 
set @rows = LookupRows("My_Data_Extension","Product_Type", @Product_Type)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @KPI_RP, @Product_Id
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
    set @Product_Id = field(@row,"Product_Id")
    set @KPI_RP= field(@row,"KPI_RP")
    ]%%
Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Product_Id: %%=v(@Product_Id)=%%, KPI_RP: %%=v(@KPI_RP)=%%

%%[next @i ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @Product_Type, @i
set @Product_Type= "SI" 
set @rows = LookupRows("My_Data_Extension","Product_Type", @Product_Type)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @KPI_SI, @Product_Id
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
    set @Product_Id = field(@row,"Product_Id")
    set @KPI_SI= field(@row,"KPI_SI")
    ]%%
Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Product_Id: %%=v(@Product_Id)=%%, KPI_SI: %%=v(@KPI_SI)=%%

%%[next @i ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @Product_Type, @i
set @Product_Type= "Co" 
set @rows = LookupRows("My_Data_Extension","Product_Type", @Product_Type)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @KPI_Co, @Product_Id
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
    set @Product_Id = field(@row,"Product_Id")
    set @KPI_Co= field(@row,"KPI_Co")
    ]%%
Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Product_Id: %%=v(@Product_Id)=%%, KPI_Co: %%=v(@KPI_Co)=%%

%%[next @i ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

This code displays me all the products and the KPI associated for each type of product but when i select a subscriberkey here :
[image]

What i want is to display all the products and KPI for the subscriberkey selected.

I hope that my question is understandable

Does someone has an idea ? Maybe I have to make this in only one `lookuprows` but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: It will be nice, if you also paste your ampscript code here. On the top of the question it looks like you have to filter your rows based on the subscriberkey.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just edited my post so as to show you my code at the moment. Not sure this is the right approach. Yes i also think that i have to filter my rows base on the subkey. should i have to do this before all my 4 lookuprows ?

Comment: Yes, you need additional parameters check. LookupRows("My_Data_Extension","Product_Type", @Product_Type,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey)

Comment: thank you so much, it works! I have a question, if I want to filter my rows based on the subkey and the email address, or on the subkey, the email address and also an other column, is it possible? do you know how many column can be used for the filter excluding my product_type ?

Comment: You can add multiple filters , but remember they all work in 'and' clause

Comment: thank you Swati !